# How can I smoothly switch versions for Java, Gradle or Maven in local development environment?

Tags: versioning, infrastructure

For different applications, I want to switch my java, gradle version of my local computer. How can I smoothly do this version change and back to the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution regarding this question. I am using **[SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/)**. The Software Development Kit Manager. SDKMAN! is a tool for managing parallel versions of multiple Software Development Kits on most Unix based systems.